# What are other options available to generate DOIs without using extensions in CKAN?

Tags: python, metadata, ckan, metadata-extractor, doi

Well, I would like to know if there is any other options that I can use to generate **DOI**s for all or newly created datasets in **CKAN** if I am not using **ckanext-doi** extension. Can someone try to explain how this is possible.

As far as I know, **DataCite** or **TIB** provides this, with **ckanext-doi** extension you can use it to assign `digitial object identifiers` (**DOI**s) to the datasets, using the DataCite DOI service they offer. When a new dataset is created it is assigned a new DOI, and this is in the format of [https://doi.org/[prefix]/[8](https://doi.org/%5Bprefix%5D/%5B8) random alphanumeric characters].

If the new dataset is active and public, then, the DOI and metadata will be registered with **DatCite** or **TIB** but if the dataset is a draft or private, the DOI is not registered until it's made active and public, hence the DOI will be submitted. Doing this allows the datasets to be embargoed, but still provides a DOI to be referenced in publications.I can either auto-generate them using **python** and **Datacite API** or manually generate them from **Fabrica**.

But, the bad news is that for me to be able to test or have access to DOI service or use with this extension, I need to have an active account with them and having an account means to be a registered member with dataCite/TIB, until this is done, minting active DOIs is not be possible and I am not or my institution is a member of DataCite/TIB yet.

So, I'm inquiring if there is any other options available with ckan other than using **DataCite** or **TIB** to generate **DOI**s,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no other way. You can develop your own plugin with a python lib called https://pypi.org/project/datacite/

Regards